Reconnecting a water heater from three-phase to single-phase (220V)
I switched from three-phase to single-phase. Since the water heater was connected using 3 phases I need to change the connection to use it (It seems it could be done by changing the red/blue wires, and/or the little metal wires attached to the base of the screw visible on the picture below ― it's possible according to the schematics).
The manufacturer can't help because the label containing the model number and other specs has been destroyed (the person who bought the heater is dead). But I found some schematics (cf. the picture below)
Measure of the heating resistor part:
(I draw a black lines between the numbers to show that there is 0Ω)

My first try:
in brief (a picture to summarize what I understand about the rewiring):

About the schematic:

it mention #5 but there is nothing on it
they put the live on #2 but it's the earth-grounded (attached to the metal case)
why is the connection between #2→#3 white/empty, while #5→#3 and 3→4 are black?
why is there a light between 2 and 4?

After switching to single-phase, I needed to power the heater at least to power the small anti-corrosion device inside (or to recharge the small battery that takes over to power the anti-corrosion during a power outage ― because it died after 48 hours).
Assuming the water heater is using three heating resistors, to limit problems, I attempted to power only one resistor. Therefore, I disconnected two red wires (refer to the pictures). I kept only one red wire connected to pin 2 of the resistor and the two blue wires on pin 1 (assuming that the blue wires are neutral).
Since the heater was originally powered by three wires connected to pins A, B, and C of the heater, I had to determine which one should be connected to the live and neutral. I tried every combination. Only two combinations turn on the heater led: 1(A=live and B=neutral), and 2(A=neutral and B=live). Initially, I thought only the first combination was working because the second one produced a high-frequency humming or buzzing noise. However, I later discovered that this was unrelated, as it also occurred sometimes with the first combination when I restarted the power. In such cases, the noise stopped when I restarted the power again.
Result: The system charges the battery (so it probably also runs its anti-oxidation feature), which is great as it provides me with some time to find a solution. However, it does not heat the water ― there is no voltage between the (only remaining) red and the blue wires of the resistors.
These Pictures show how it was connected with the tree-phases :


I found these schematics
(on the plastic cover that protects the parts shown on the picture).



this is not an electronics design question ... please drlete it and ask at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions

The diagram marked "230 V ~" is exactly what you want. It's pretty clear from the resistance measurements that the elements are wired in a "Y" configuration, so you just need to connect all the "live" terminals together as shown to put them in parallel with each other.

@DaveTweed Thanks a lot for your help. We know a bit about diagrams but we do not understand this one. How exactly should we rewire the water heater? Based on this image i.sstatic.net/rE7uXBmk.png should we : a) add a wire between 1 and 6 ; b) add a wire between 4 and 6 ; c) remove the current red wire on 4 ; d) remove the current red wire on 1 and connect it to 3 (on the schematics it should be 2, but as you can see on the picture, nothing it connected to 2) ; e) leave the silvery wires as they are.

Is there a reason you must do this yourself? It sounds like you should call a licenced electrician to do the connections. In some jurisdictions, it would be illegal for a person without proper training to perform that kind of electrical work.

The diagram indicates that you should connect terminals 1, 4, 6 together, and separately from those, connect 2, 3, and 5.
The diagrams also show some links formed by something other than wire, maybe a bus bar -- one joining 4 to 6, which you can leave alone, and one joining 1 to 5, which you'll have to move to 3 and 5.  There's also a hollow indication of an existing link from 2 to 3, which you would leave in place -- but your ohmmeter said that's not present.  Oh, you switched the numbering on the ohmmeter results.
What's inconsistent is that your current setup should not have had a phase connected to both 4 and 6... it looks like 4 should have been connected only to the lamp.  Is there any possibility you're looking at the circuit from the wrong side, so that you have the labels on 2 and 4 swapped?  The 230V 3-phase diagram has phases connected at 1, 2, and 6.
You should use your ohmmeter again on the remaining terminals.  If there's a link/busbar on those that you don't see, and you power on without accounting for that, it would be bad.
If you get this wrong and are lucky you'd get away with only tripped circuit breakers. Middle luck would be permanent damage to the equipment, and bad luck a house fire.  So measure everything a couple extra times before turning on power.  In the end you're expecting to have ~20 ohms (3 resistors in parallel) between your line and neutral.

Also be sure that the in-wall circuit is rated for the current, which will be significantly higher delivering the same power to the water heater from only a single phase.

Thanks for your help! It's not that easy. I edited the pictures of my question to show that #2 is earth grounded (I thus believe it should not be connected to the neutral), and there is nothing on #5 (it's just a number written in an empty space). It seems the people who built it made a mistake: they fitted the connection into the plastic holes without caring about the number. The schematic thus doesn't help. But the measurement we made should show the way (for specialists like you).

@JinSnow: I see you updated the meter measurement diagram to use the same numbering scheme.  That definitely indicates to connect 1-4-6 to either phase or neutral, and the 3 to the other.  2 is ground (and also the metal enclosure, that's correct for safety).  Are you sure about the 0 ohm readings between 2 and (everything else)?  Could those actually be open circuit / infinity (often appears as "OL" on a meter, shorthand for "overload", or "High" meaning too high to measure)?

Thanks again! I triple tested again, I confirm there is 0Ω between 2 and everything else. I tested both using the continuity bip, and ohmmeter (I'm using the "unit t clamp meter" which is wildly use by professionals). Here is a better picture (with the rewiring ― by safety I disconnected 2 out of the 3 red wires as explained in my question) https://imgur.com/xvR9V5o  . I find it very strange that these resistors connections are touching the casing.

(I also don't understand how it is possible that there is a continuity between pin 2 and 1 and between pin 2 and 3 but no continuity between pin 1 and 3)

I moved the question here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/298479/reconnecting-a-water-heater-from-three-phase-to-single-phase-220v
